# Issue with WHILE loop in PSQL shell

Tags: shell, while-loop, psql, greenplum

I'm trying to use a WHILE LOOP to insert columns from a collection of tables in PSQL shell. Code is as follows:

```
\set start_id 909
\set end_iter 912

-- Create base table to be later inserted
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t_base_table;
CREATE TEMP TABLE t_base_table (
...
)
DISTRIBUTED RANDOMLY;

SELECT :start_id AS iter \gset

BEGIN

  WHILE :iter <= :end_iter LOOP

    \set weekly 'table_i_want_col_from_':iter

    INSERT INTO t_base_table
      SELECT ... --same columns as in the base table
      FROM :weekly a
      GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6

  SELECT :iter+1 AS iter \gset

  END LOOP;
END;
```

I got several error messages:

- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHILE" LINE 2:   WHILE 909 <= 912 LOOP
- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 13:   SELECT 909+1 AS week_id
- ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LOOP" LINE 1: END LOOP;

Looks like when I ran the script, it got split up in the psql shell (thus the 'LINE 1' in the item 3 above). I'm wondering is it because this syntax is not valid for psql shell? Or am I using the \set or \gset in a wrong way.

Thanks in advance for any help you may provide!!

Comment: this isn't postgresql. Redshift? greenplum?

Comment: @CraigRinger Sorry about the confusion. This is in greenplum, but I'm using psql command line to run it.

Comment: You seem to be trying to do a bare plpgsql block. Don't know if Greenplum supports that, but PostgreSQL proper does not.